How numpy.linalg.norm works
I am trying to understand how these numbers calculated:
>>> np.linalg.norm([1,2,3,4,5],0)
5.0
>>> np.linalg.norm([1,2,3,4,5],1)
15.0
>>> np.linalg.norm([1,2,3,4,5],2)
7.416198487095663
>>> np.linalg.norm([1,2,3,4,5],3)
6.082201995573399
>>> np.linalg.norm([1,2,3,4,5],4)
5.593654949523078

How np.linalg.norm works?

The documentation is pretty clear about how it works, and has an entire table that shows you exactly what math gets used to compute the norm, based on the norm order value you specified.

...and given the above, what's the narrow, specific place where that documentation is unclear? Right now it reads like this is a request for people to just rewrite general documentation and hope that somehow the new version will make more sense to you than the existing form does -- that's not a very efficient use of volunteers' time.

As per the documentation:

If ord=0: numpy returns the number of nonzero elements in the array.
If ord is an integer: numpy returns sum(abs(x)**ord)**(1./ord), i.e we raise the absolute value of each element to the power of ord, sum them, and then take that result to the power of 1/ord. I show the mathematical notation below (this is known as the p-norm).


